# Tastypie with Django 1.8 giving Content type not found error

Tags: python, django, tastypie

In trying to upgrade my TastyPie app to Django 1.8 but am getting an error message:

> Content type for specified type 'html' not found. Please provide it at either the class level or via the arguments.

This happens when the `serializer=...` is executed in the following Python code:

```
class PeopleResource(ModelResource):
    movie = fields.ToManyField('movies.api.MovieResource', 'movie', related_name="casts", null=True)      
    class Meta:
        queryset = People.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'people'
        include_resource_uri = False
        always_return_data = True
        authorization= Authorization()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json', 'jsonp', 'xml', 'yaml', 'html', 'plist'])
        filtering = {
            'name': ALL,
            'id': ALL,
        }
```

I don't understand the instruction to provide at class level or by parameter).

Comment: Hmm, if you remove `html` from the format list, does it work?

Comment: Yes it does work if I remove 'html'

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html#configuring-allowed-formats):

The default Serializer supports the following formats:

- json
- jsonp (Disabled by default)
- xml
- yaml
- plist (see http://explorapp.com/biplist/)

Comment: Are you aware of an html serialiser I can plug in?

Comment: Why do you want to use html as a serializer?

Comment: Good question! I have just taken over this code so I am not sure.